# Less common HTTP Status Code

Tags: http, jakarta-ee

Maybe I'm trying to get fired, but I really want to add this error page I made:

[image]

But since we all know that it's not really that appropriate, I would like to put it in an HTTP Status that user will less likely encounter.

So what error code should I use?

Thank you.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code><!--SUGGESTIONS HERE--></error-code>
    <location>/errors/overly-attached-error-page.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Hold on ... *that* is enough of an offense to get you fired? Mind telling us where exactly you are employed? People's TelCo of Dictabrutistan?

Answer (score 0):

[`418 I'm a teapot`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2324). No server would send this unless it was specifically configured to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [this page](http://royal.pingdom.com/2009/05/06/the-5-most-common-http-errors-according-to-google/) suggests a good pick for a common, yet not too common error code were [`401/Unauthorized`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1). My personal preference were [`417/Expectation failed`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.14): there is virtually no commonly used web browser out there that would send out an `Expect: 100-continue` header as part of a request, which woudl be needed to have even a *chance* of triggering this error. Some techies with special-purpose clients may still get to see it, however.